# Website Database Design Hotel Features

Tags: html, sql, web

I am creating a website and have a design issue with regards to features of a property.

When a property is created it is stored in a database and then when it is displayed on the website it is read using PHP and is working fine.

However, requirements have been updated and I now need to include features that the rooms have such as double bed, tv's, air conditioning etc.  I originally thought that the best way in which to include this would be adding a new row to the properties table but I'm unsure how i would order this into bullet points on the website.

Below is the current database table.

[Database currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Y5Z7.png)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a table called Properties that is just 2 columns: a list of all the possible properties and an id column(primary key).

Then have a table called RoomProperties that is a RoomId, a PropertyId, and a value(this could be a varchar or int depending on what could possibly go in there).

Then you can join on Rooms, Properties, and RoomProperties to get all the info you would need.